# Free distributable XML Editor / Validator

Tags: xml, validation, editor

I am looking for a FREE XML Editor/ Validator that I can distribute as part of my product.
Does anyone familiar with such tool ?

Thanks,
Munish

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if you can distribute it as part of your product. 
But perhaps you could provide a link to [XML Notepad 2007](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=72D6AA49-787D-4118-BA5F-4F30FE913628&displaylang=en) from Microsoft?

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, I misread question...

Would [Altova Authentic](http://www.altova.com/download/authentic/xml_db_form_editor_desktop.html) (free) suit your purpose?

Answer (score 0):

I can recommend [JEdit](http://www.jedit.org/), with the "XML" plugin (see Plugins section on website).

It lets you edit XML, does validation against a DTD or XSD, displays element trees in the sidekick dockable. Also has completion popups for elements, attribute, and entities.

It is free software (GPL), so you can distribute freely.

Answer (score 0):

[Sharpdeveop](http://www.icsharpcode.net/OpenSource/SD/), does have XML editor available as plug-in, which can be extracted out and and shipped to.

IMHO, XML Notepad from MS are not so good.

Answer (score 0):

Notepad++ with XML Utilties - but check the licensing first!

Answer (score 0):

Oxygen is excellent, but is not free.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use camv library to build your own tool, as long as you have the validation rules template, which can be generated from schema at modify it to suit your own business, and then wrap it with your code (UI), would be much more to the point (to meet your specific requirement)

herewith a simple tutorial of how to integrate camv with your code.

http://www.zenmeo.com/wordpress/xml-validation-using-camv-framework-tutorial/